# XSLT Templates and applying templates

Tags: xslt

I am very new to XSLT and I am having a hard time understanding some of its concepts.

I have the following XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

<Page>
    <Page>
        <Page />
    </Page>
    <Page>
        <Page />
    </Page>
    <Page />
    <Page />
    <Page />
</Page>
```

And when the following XSL file (test.xsl) is applied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates name="PageCount" />
        </h2>
    </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Page" name="PageCount">
     Page <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
     of <xsl:value-of select="count(/Page/Page)" />

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the output:

**Page 2 of 5**

However if I change the "apply-templates" to "call-template" it changes the output to:

**Page 1 of 5**

Why does this happen?

Also if I add another template:

```
  <xsl:template match="Page" name="PageCount2">
    Page <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
    of <xsl:value-of select="count(/Page)" />
  </xsl:template>
```

and use "apply-templates" it seems gives me the output:

**Page 2 of 1**

This is baffling to me. What is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't get any output for `<xsl:apply-templates name="PageCount" />` - it's a syntax error (apply-templates takes a select attribute, not a name attribute). Are you sure that's what you wrote?

Comment: @Michael Kay - I believe that @ dherrin79 wants to know the difference between `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and `<xsl:call-template name="PageCount"/>` (which produces the described output) and why it evaluates differently.

Comment: @MichaelKay - This is exactly what I wrote, as I just pasted it right in to my question.  However thank you for the insight. I did not know that name was not a valid attribute for the "apply-templates" command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, it is really short for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` and is being invoked inside of a template match on `/`, which is the root node of the document and an abstract concept for the top of the file.  It's children include the document element (i.e. `<Page>`), as well as any top-level comments or processing instructions that may be siblings of the document element.

So, **when you are "standing" on the root node, the call to `<xsl:apply-templates/>` will apply templates to `/Page`, which matches the template that you define.**  `position()` is evaluated from the matched context, which is `/Page`, and returns `2`, because it is the second item in the document.  The first item is the xml-stylesheet processing instruction. If you were to remove it, then `position()` would evaluate to `1`.

**When you use `<xsl:call-template name="PageCount"/>`, it invokes the same template, but the context does not change when the template is called.**  You are still "standing" on the root node, so `position()` evaluates to `1`.

The `count()` always evaluates the same, regardless of the context, because it uses an XPath that starts at the root node.  If you were to change it to `count(Page/Page)` and evaluate relative from the context node, then you would get different values(`2` and `5` respectively).

Comment: Thanks for the insight you provided.  It was very helpful and clearly explained.